# Xmpp client application in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmpp

I need to develop a web application in asp.net using with XMPP protocol or (Openfire) technology and if user can send message from this website then message should be delivered on mobile app user as well and vise-versa. Please suggest me how can we create that type of application in asp.net.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use a .NET XMPP library in your backend in combination with a realtime channel like SignalR.
Or use a JavaScript XMPP library using BOSH or Websockets and do all the XMPP programming in JS.